# How to pass arguments from command line to Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-task, gradle-properties

I'm trying to pass an argument from command line to a Java class.  I followed this post: http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Gradle-application-plugin-question-td5539555.html but the code does not work for me (perhaps it is not meant for JavaExec?).  Here is what I tried:

```groovy
task listTests(type:JavaExec){
    main = "util.TestGroupScanner"
    classpath = sourceSets.util.runtimeClasspath
    // this works...
    args 'demo'
    /*
    // this does not work!
    if (project.hasProperty("group")){
        args group
    }
    */
}
```

The output from the above hard coded args value is:

```
C:\ws\svn\sqe\sandbox\selenium2forbg\testgradle>g listTests
:compileUtilJava UP-TO-DATE
:processUtilResources UP-TO-DATE
:utilClasses UP-TO-DATE
:listTests
Received argument: demo

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 13.422 secs
```

However, once I change the code to use the hasProperty section and pass "demo" as an argument on the command line, I get a NullPointerException:

```
C:\ws\svn\sqe\sandbox\selenium2forbg\testgradle>g listTests -Pgroup=demo -s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\ws\svn\sqe\sandbox\selenium2forbg\testgradle\build.gradle' line:25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'testgradle'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project
 'testgradle'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
```

There is a simple test project available at http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/file/n5709919/testgradle.zip that illustrates the problem.

This is using Gradle 1.0-rc-3.  The NullPointer is from this line of code:

```groovy
  args group
```

I added the following assignment before the task definition, but it didn't change the outcome:

```groovy
  group = hasProperty('group') ? group : 'nosuchgroup'
```

Any pointers on how to pass command line arguments to Gradle appreciated.

Comment: TNX alot @Joshua Goldberg.   sample for one argument: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58202665/2201814

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle task - pass arguments to Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604283/gradle-task-pass-arguments-to-java-application)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`project.group` is a predefined property. With `-P`, you can only set project properties that are *not* predefined. Alternatively, you can set Java system properties (`-D`).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!  Changing name to testngGroup fixed the problem.  Found a list of predefined properties in table 13.1 at http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html.

Comment: Just to update the link: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties

Comment: As of July 2018 there's a much simpler way.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463332/5486) below.

Answer (score 59):

As noted in a comment, my solution is superceded by the newer built-in `--args` option in gradle.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463332/411282) from @madhead or [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27604283/411282).

---

Building on Peter N's answer, this is an example of how to add (optional) user-specified arguments to pass to Java main for a JavaExec task (since you can't set the 'args' property manually for the reason he cites.)

Add this to the task:

```
task(runProgram, type: JavaExec) {

  [...]

  if (project.hasProperty('myargs')) {
      args(myargs.split(','))
  }
```

... and run at the command line like this

```
% ./gradlew runProgram '-Pmyargs=-x,7,--no-kidding,/Users/rogers/tests/file.txt'
```

Comment: How could I go about having separate parameters?  E.g: `gradle run -Purl='localhost', -Pport='8080', -Pusername='admin'  ` how would my code in build.gradle should look like?

Comment: @Tomas I'd suggest fleshing out a top-level question for that.  (I don't know that situation well enough to give a quick inline answer here myself, anyway.)

Comment: No worries, did it already and got sorted out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875637/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-command-line-when-running-gradle-task)

Comment: As of July 2018 there's a much simpler way.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463332/5486) below.

Answer (score 29):

My program with two arguments, args[0] and args[1]:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(args);
    String host = args[0];
    System.out.println(host);
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

my build.gradle

```
run {
    if ( project.hasProperty("appArgsWhatEverIWant") ) {
        args Eval.me(appArgsWhatEverIWant)
    }
}
```

my terminal prompt:

```
gradle run  -PappArgsWhatEverIWant="['localhost','8080']"
```

Comment: As of July 2018 there's a much simpler way.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463332/5486) below.

Answer (score 28):

As of Gradle 4.9 Application plugin understands `--args` option, so passing the arguments is as simple as:

*build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = "my.App"
```

*src/main/java/my/App.java*

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args);
    }
}
```

*bash*

```
./gradlew run --args='This string will be passed into my.App#main arguments'
```

or in Windows, use double quotes:

```
gradlew run --args="This string will be passed into my.App#main arguments"
```

Comment: At time of comment this seems to be the best (as in simplest that works) answer

Answer (score 25):

You can use custom command line options in Gradle:

```
./gradlew printPet --pet="Puppies!"
```

Custom command line options were an [incubating feature](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_lifecycle.html) in Gradle 5.0 but became public in Gradle 6.0.

## Java solution

Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:declaring_and_using_command_line_options):

```java
import org.gradle.api.tasks.options.Option;

public class PrintPet extends DefaultTask {
    private String pet;

    @Option(option = "pet", description = "Name of the cute pet you would like to print out!")
    public void setPet(String pet) {
        this.pet = pet;
    }

    @Input
    public String getPet() {
        return pet;
    }

    @TaskAction
    public void print() {
        getLogger().quiet("'{}' are awesome!", pet);
    }
}
```

Then register it:

```
task printPet(type: PrintPet)
```

Now you can do:

```
./gradlew printPet --pet="Puppies!"
```

output:

> Puppies! are awesome!

## Kotlin solution

```kotlin
open class PrintPet : DefaultTask() {

    @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
    @set:Option(option = "pet", description = "The cute pet you would like to print out")
    @get:Input
    var pet: String = ""

    @TaskAction
    fun print() {    
        println("$pet are awesome!")
    }
}
```

then register the task with:

```
tasks.register<PrintPet>("printPet")
```

Comment: Saved my day, the problem with me was using `get` instead of `set` in the `@set:Option`

Answer (score 8):

If you need to check and set **one argument**, your `build.gradle` file would be like this:

```
....

def coverageThreshold = 0.15

if (project.hasProperty('threshold')) {
    coverageThreshold = project.property('threshold').toString().toBigDecimal()
}

//print the value of variable
println("Coverage Threshold: $coverageThreshold")
...
```

And the Sample command in windows:

> gradlew clean test -Pthreshold=0.25

Answer (score 4):

I have written a piece of code that puts the command line arguments in the format that gradle expects.

```
// this method creates a command line arguments
def setCommandLineArguments(commandLineArgs) {
    // remove spaces 
    def arguments = commandLineArgs.tokenize()

            // create a string that can be used by Eval 
            def cla = "["
            // go through the list to get each argument
            arguments.each {
                    cla += "'" + "${it}" + "',"
            }

    // remove last "," add "]" and set the args 
    return cla.substring(0, cla.lastIndexOf(',')) + "]"
}
```

my task looks like this:

```
task runProgram(type: JavaExec) {
    if ( project.hasProperty("commandLineArgs") ) {
            args Eval.me( setCommandLineArguments(commandLineArgs) )
    }
}
```

To pass the arguments from the command line you run this:

```
gradle runProgram -PcommandLineArgs="arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4"
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a great example here:

https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Gradle_Pass_Configuration_on_Command_Line

Which details that you can pass parameters and then provide a default in an ext variable like so:

```
gradle -Dmy_app.color=blue
```

and then reference in Gradle as:

```
ext {
   color = System.getProperty("my_app.color", "red");
}
```

And then anywhere in your build script you can reference it as  course anywhere you can reference it as `project.ext.color`

More tips here: https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Gradle_Variables_and_Properties

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts).

I first try to get the variable as a property and if it was `null` try to get it from OS environment variables (can be useful in CIs like GitHub Actions).

```kotlin
tasks.create("MyCustomTask") {
    val songName = properties["songName"]
        ?: System.getenv("SONG_NAME")
        ?: error("""Property "songName" or environment variable "SONG_NAME" not found""")

    // OR getting the property with 'by'. Did not work for me!
    // For this approach, name of the variable should be the same as the property name
    // val songName: String? by properties

    println("The song name: $songName")
}
```

We can then pass a value for the property from command line:

```sh
./gradlew MyCustomTask -PsongName="Black Forest"
```

Or create a file named *local.properties* at the root of the project and set the property:

```
songName=Black Forest
```

We can also [add an env variable](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html) named `SONG_NAME` with our desired value and then run the task:

```sh
./gradlew MyCustomTask
```

Answer (score -5):

pass a url from command line keep your url in app gradle file as follows
 **resValue "string", "url", CommonUrl**

and give a parameter in gradle.properties files as follows 
**CommonUrl="put your url here or may be empty"**

and pass a command to from command line as follows
**gradle assembleRelease -Pcommanurl=put your URL here**