# Run same gradle Task to generate java class from xsd using plugin xjc with different parameters

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have two gradle task genJaxb and genJaxb2  to generate java code from xsd. They both do the same thing only difference is they generate stub from different files. Is there any to have one task with parameters and call them to avoid duplication.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.4.2"
    id 'jacoco'

}

group = 'com.abc'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory.three.com/artifactory/libs-release"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}

// tag::xsd[]
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir 'build/generated-sources/jaxb'
            srcDir 'build/invoice/generated-sources/jaxb'
        }
    }
}

task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "src/main/resources/text.xsd"

    outputs.dir sourcesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema) {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }
        }
    }
}

task genJaxb2 {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/test1/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "src/main/resources/test1.xsd"

    outputs.dir sourcesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema) {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }
        }
    }
}



compileJava.dependsOn genJaxb,genJaxb2
// end::xsd[]

// tag::jaxb[]
configurations {
    jaxb
    
}

bootJar {
    archiveBaseName = 'invoicedelivery/201306'
    archiveVersion =  '0.1.0'
}
// end::jaxb[]


dependencies {
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
     implementation 'wsdl4j:wsdl4j'
     jaxb("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc")
     implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.1'
     testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
     implementation 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:3.0.6'
     implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.6'
     implementation 'com.github.dozermapper:dozer-spring-boot-starter:6.2.0'
     implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.0.1'
     testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.4.0'
}


tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.named('test') {

    useJUnitPlatform()
}

plugins.withType(JacocoPlugin) {
    tasks["test"].finalizedBy 'jacocoTestReport'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }
}
```

The end goal is to have one gradle task instead of two to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters to Gradle task using `-P` (project property) and `-D` (System property) options.
These properties can be read in Gradle script using `project.getProperty()` and `system.getProperty()`

e.g. Gradle task is as mentioned below

```
task firstTask {
    doFirst {
       println myArg
     }
}
```

and then execute the task using below command

```
./gradlew firstTask -PmyArg=hi
```

I also found another thread explaining this; please check [How to pass parameters or arguments into a gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410854/how-to-pass-parameters-or-arguments-into-a-gradle-task/48370451#48370451)

Other more complicated option would be to create custom tasktype and then use `-q` option to execute task with custom parameters.
Please check below URL for this.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:declaring_and_using_command_line_options

Comment: Thanks for your reply All the parameters are known before running the task so I am looking for simple way to invoke the gradle task can you please provide more hint with property

Comment: @akashsharma3030 I have updated above answer.