# Use "Variable Value" as Key in Springboot application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Consider a below configuration in application.yml

```
service:
    id: status-service

provider:
    ${service.id}: "Running"
```

I need to create a key using a value from so that the configuration can show up like

```
service:
    id: status-service

provider:
    status-service: "Running"
```

I have tried following but either I get expression as a string or parsing error:

```
${service.id}
[service.id]
[[service.id]]
[${service.id}]
%service.id%
```

I am using SpringBoot(2.7) with Gradle 7.6.1

Comment: how did you provide the value of ${service.id} to gradle ? what command did you use? like https://stackoverflow.com/a/26510706/175554

Comment: @ozkanpakdil, I have set the value in the yml itself like described above in the message.