# Pass command line arguments to gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-2

To start Java program, I can pass arguments like:

```
java Main arg1 arg2 arg3
```

What are the good ways to do that in gradle command line:

```
gradle startProgram arg1 arg2 arg3
```

And this is in build.gradle:

```
task startProgram(dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments from command line to gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696521/how-to-pass-arguments-from-command-line-to-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use java system properties (`-D` switch) but these are more 'global'. Instead You can use simple properties (`-P` switch) and get the passed values using instance of `Project` class.