# Calling a shell script with arguments in Gradle

Tags: shell, groovy, gradle, arguments

I have a shell script which I want to call from within gradle. 
The shell script takes optarg like arguments which have to passed to the command line with -P arguments of gradle but I have been unable to think of a better way to do this.

My script is called as below:

```
./script.ksh -a arg1 -b arg2
```

My gradle task looks like below

```
task Build(type: Exec ) {
        workingDir rootProject.projectDir.path
        executable rootProject.projectDir.path + "/script.ksh"
}
```

I have tried using "args" but couldn't get this working.

What I am looking for is trying to pass these arguments to gradle in the below format

```
gradle build ARG1 ARG2
```

Comment: Is the gradle call inside the shell script? Also, which gradle version?

Comment: @fhrd no no, gradle call is at the prompt. gradle is calling the script from build.gradle.

Comment: This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19256949/995572) worked.