# How to pass multiple parameters in command line when running gradle task?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I've got a java and groovy classes that are being run by gradle task. I have managed to make it work but I do not like the way I have to pass the parameters in command line. Here is how I do it currently via command line: `gradle runTask -Pmode"['doStuff','username','password']"`
my build.gradle code which takes these parameters looks like this:

```
if (project.hasProperty("mode")) {
args Eval.me(mode)}
```

and then I use my arguments/parameters in my java code as follows:

```
String action = args[0]; //"doStuff"
String name = args[1]; .. //"username"
```

I was wondering is there a way to pass the parameters in a better way such as:

```
gradle runTask -Pmode=doStuff -Puser=username -Ppass=password
```

and how to use them in my java classes.

Comment: I assume these java classes are part of a project code, which is run by gradle, am I correct? How does your task run them?

Comment: @Adam Yes you're right, my task run them using javaexec and it runs main() method in one of the java classes

Comment: ok, I understood the problem, wait a few minutes for an answer)

Comment: Command line arguments passed to `main` are not a map. What you already have is the common way of working with them. It looks like you're trying to use them like system properties, which are intentionally different. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696521

Comment: @blgt so this means that my way(using an array of parameters) is the only way to pass parameters via command line in this situation? I mean I can use it my but I was looking for a better way than this as it is quite open for human error with all these quote-marks and brackets

Comment: @Tomas WEll gradle is a build tool, so you don't generally expect to be passing a ton of command line args to/via it. `JavaExec` might be there to help you but in this case it looks more like it's forcing you into a box

Comment: @blgt Thanks for your time, JavaExec indeed helped as posted in answer by AdamSkyWalker

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) may be the way to go. Just declare a task and pass project parameters to java app:

```
task myExecTask(type: JavaExec) {
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   main = 'com.project.MyApplicationMainClass' 
   args project.getProperty('userName') + ' ' + project.getProperty('password');
}
```

To run it, simply write `gradle myExecTask -PuserName=john -Ppassword=secret`

Comment: Brilliant, worked like a charm and just what I needed, thank you Sir!

Comment: any ideas about  this? What if I want to run that same task but without getting some of the properties, e.g I want to run the task  just with `gradle myExecTask -Pmode=doStuff ` and not `gradle myExecTask -Pmode=doStuff -PuserName=john -Ppassword=secret` , it throws me and error saying that properties 'usernName' and 'password' were not found..

Comment: @Tomas yes, gradle throws annoying exceptions when property is not present. The only way to do avoid it is to first call project.hasProperty('name') to check if property was set.

Comment: Yeah I went down that path and managed to sort that out now, cheers

Comment: Shouldnt the parameters be separated by commas instead of spaces? i.e. `args project.getProperty('userName'), project.getProperty('password');` instead of `args project.getProperty('userName') + ' ' + project.getProperty('password');`

Comment: @RiteshTendulkar you are right, args parameter in JavaExec task has Iterable type, so using comma is more correct. Spaces work too because at the end iterable params become a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
task myExecTask(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'com.project.MyApplicationMainClass' 
  args(user, pass); // no need to access user and pass via project.getProperty()
}
```

- args needs to be built as a List of Strings for java main to use.
- args now should be in the form of : ['myusername', 'mypassword']

Answer (score 0):

this is the task I had to create for passing arguments through gradle
 task

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            systemProperties = [
                    usr: project.getProperty('usr'),
                    pwd: project.getProperty('pwd')
            ]
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'location to step def', 'location to feature files']
        }
    }
}
```

in order to execute test
`$ gradle cucumber -Pusr=<username> -Ppwd=<password>`

to access args in your code `System.getProperty("usr"), System.getProperty("pwd")`