# Run custom gradle taks from the terminal

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I created a custom `Gradle` task for running from terminal in a separate file named `feature.gradle`, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34876223/10349175) and Gradle docs

```
task("withFeature", JavaExec::class) {
    group = "myCustomTasks"
    main = "com.example.calculator"
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
    args(feature)
```

}

and register task in `Gradle`

```
tasks.register("withFeature")
```

`feature` is a property (string) that I want to pass into test (for now it's unit test, but later it would be android UI test)

```
    @Test
    fun getPackArgs() {
        val property = System.getProperty("feature")
        Assert.assertEquals("default", property)
    }
```

But when i write next command, where `-Pfeature=default` is what i wants to pass into code

```
./gradlew test withFeature -Pfeature=default
```

test fails, and `System.getProperty("feature")` is null :

```
expected:<default> but was:<null>
Expected :default
Actual   :null
```

Can anyone elaborate what i am doing wrong while running task with argument, which should pass into test package ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are confusing system properties `-D` and project properties `-P` the latter you can access via `project.property("feature")`. Also `task("withFeature", JavaExec::class)` already declares the task so `tasks.register("withFeature")` is redundant/harmful.

Comment: @user16358266 Thanks for an answer, but how I can access project.property("feature") from the test package ?