# How to provide command line argument to build task

Tags: gradle

How to provide command line argument to build task?

For instance, I want to download 60 build version from an archive to my local server path.
Could you please suggest how can I achieve this?

Example task:

```
    task download(type: Download) {
        src 'http://archiva/repository/test/$version/project-$version.jar'
        dest new File(buildDir, '../../../test/project.jar')
        username 'username'
        password 'password'
}
```

gradle download version=60

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments from command line to gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696521/how-to-pass-arguments-from-command-line-to-gradle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Project Properties* for this purpose (see [Project Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties))

Example: consider the following task

```
task hello{
    doLast{
        println "Hello ${project.findProperty('myProp')}"
    }
}
```

You can pass property value as follows:

```
./gradlew hello -PmyProp=world
```

**Note** you should use another variable name than "version", as `version` is already a Gradle property attached to the project.

**Note 2** :  I noticed you are using simple quote for `src` value, this cannot work. You need to se double-quote for String interpolation ( see [here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) ):

Use:

```
src "http://archiva/repository/test/$version/project-$version.jar"
```

instead of:

```
src 'http://archiva/repository/test/$version/project-$version.jar'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  At the first i have used project property archivaVersion and it worked. But problem is i do not want to provide argument to other task too. while executing other task it is failing due to unknown property error. Hence i am using my own property as you explained above..