# How do i setup gradle test command with environment name

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to gradle and learning as I go. I've tests that I can kick off using gradle command in my terminal. The issue I'm running into is that I have to keep two copies of the same test, one for QA  and one for Staging environment. They are similar tests the reason for this is that I have no idea how to set up gradle in a way that I can just tell it to run testA on QA or Staging
My Current gradle.build file looks like this

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.14.3'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
    compile 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:3.3.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
}
test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

My current gradle command looks like this for QA

```
gradle test --tests testlandingpageQA
```

or for Staging

```
gradle test --tests testlandingpageDev
```

I need a solution where end user can pick which environment to run this test on.

Comment: you may have to get your url from an environment variable or a property file (and have several property files: test-it.qa.properties, test-it.staging.properties). But at the end, you have to run gradle with a custom command line argument. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696521/how-to-pass-arguments-from-command-line-to-gradle

Comment: I understand what you are saying but have zero idea how to implement it. I looked at the link and tbh I have no idea whats goiing on Im lost.

Comment: For a simple case, you should have gradle set without the url as an command line argument. 

Then, in your test class, in a method annotated with @Before, you get this url from an environment variable or a Java property (System.getEnv("xxx") or System.getProperty("xxx")). 

At the end, set manually this value then run gradle without the url as a command line argument.

Bonus: set this env/property variable as a command line argument for gradle (see previous link).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working in build.gradle file I had to define system property

```
test {
systemProperty 'env', System.properties['env'] ?: 'staging'

useTestNG()
}
```

In java I had to do

```
    String environment = System.getProperty("env");
        driver.get("https://" + environment + ".somewebsite.com");
```

Finally in the console/terminal I can run something like

```
gradle -Denv=Dev test --tests testlandingpage
```

Hopefully it helps others who are trying to figure this out