# How to get an argument from command line using Gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm trying to get an argument from the command line using a Gradle task:

```
class myApk extends DefaultTask {

    @Option(option="apkName", description="apkName for your file")
    String apkName
    
    @TaskAction
    void uploadApk() {
        def arg = "curl -F \"demo${apkName}.apk=" +
                  "@${project.projectDir}\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\app-debug.apk\" " +
                  "https://URL"
        project.exec {
            commandLine("cmd", "/c", arg)
        }
    }
}
task uploadApk(type: myApk) { }
```

But after typing  `gradle uploadApk --apkName=foo` in the terminal I get this kind of exception:

```
Problem configuring task :app:uploadApk from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--apkName'.
```

P.S. I've read this topic([How to pass arguments from command line to gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696521/how-to-pass-arguments-from-command-line-to-gradle)), but it doesn't seem helpful for this problem;(

Comment: use `-PapkName=myvalue` to pass gradle project parameters

Comment: Your example works fine for me. What version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: can we pass command line arguments to settings.gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment above, I used -P to work it out