# Gradle task with argument

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have a task, something like:

```
task doSomething(type: Exec){

   commandLine "cmd", "/c", "flavour"

}
```

How can I made a specific variable and pass it into this method ?
I tried something like this:

```
task doSomething(type: Exec, myVariable: String){
    
       commandLine "cmd", "/c", "$myVariable"
    
    }
```

but it doesn't work

and i would like to assing this value in productFlavours like:

```
productFLavors {

flavor1{
myVariable = "flavor1"
}

flavour2{
myVariable = "flavor2"
}

}
```

I tried everything and I'm still getting errors :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're confusing bash/groovy string interpolation with just using the variable...

Try:

```
task doSomething(type: Exec) {
       commandLine "cmd", "/c", myVariable
}
```

```sh
./gradlew doSomething -P myVariable="something"
```

Comment: "Could not create task 'doSomething': Unknown argument(s) in task definition: [myVariable]

Comment: Updated comment with working solution. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696521/how-to-pass-arguments-from-command-line-to-gradle

Comment: nice, but do you know also how to pass argument if you want to run task it in this way: 
preBuild.dependsOn doSomething - from the gradle, not command line

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks its all in the documentation :) You'll find a google search for "dependsOn gradle" likely returns 1000s of examples you can readily adapt